# How can i replace lines Serially?

Tags: notepad

i have two very very long texts, like this:

text number 1:

```
# @ woothemes
#: comments.php:23
msgstr "text1"
msgstr ""
```

text number 2:

```
# @ woothemes
#: comments.php:23
msgid "text2"
msgstr ""
```

the result need to be like this:

```
# @ woothemes
#: comments.php:23
msgid "text2"
msgstr "text1"
```

actually, i need to copy alot of the line

```
msgstr "text1"
```

and replace it instead

```
msgstr ""
```

its will take alot of time to do it for 20,000 times, you can suggest me software that can help me in this work ? thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This seems like a good use case for a visual `diff` utility. Since you wrote tagged with notepad, I'll assume you're on windows and recommend [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that all blocks have exactly 4 lines.

1. Import 1st file into Excel, column `A`
2. Import 2nd file into Excel, column `B`
3. For first 4 rows, create 4 formulas in column `C`, which copy necessary data into `C1..C4`
4. Select `C1..C4`
5. Double-click dot in bottom-right corner of selection so `C1..C4` gets copied into column `C` along the whole height of column `B`. The following screen clipping shows the situation right before the double-clicking the dot:
   [image]
6. Copy column `C` to output file